# Using Chain of Responsibility pattern in machine learning

Tags: c++, design-patterns, machine-learning, software-design

I've read a lot of C++ and Java code of machine learning where each hidden layer is called inside a for loop. Why is the pattern *Chain of Responsability* never used ? What is its disavantages ?

-Classic approach:

```
std::vector<Layer> layers(10);
for(Layer& hidden : layers)
  hidden.activation();
```

-With Chain of Responsability:

```
std::vector<Layer*> layers();
// ... init layers vector ...
layers[0]->nextLayer(layers[1]);
layers[1]->nextLayer(layers[2]);
layers[2]->nextLayer(layers[3]);
// and so on...
layers[0]->activation();
```

In Layer:

```
Layer::activation()
{
  // do something
  nextLayer->activation();
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: What is the benefit if I write my own chain if I can also have a std::list which I can iterate over? The data structure did not directly represent the implement design pattern, it only is a way of implementing it.

Comment: This is not a chain of responsibility. This is straight copypasta.

Comment: I think the classic approach is generic enough. If it is serial computations, it is exactly the same computation pipeline you describe in the chain of responsibilities method. However, the classic version _could_ benefit from parallelism. `activation` method calls _could_ be asynchronous, and inside these functions each layer is allowed to do pre-processing while waiting for the output of the previous layer to be ready.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The advantages of the for loop is that the `layers` collection could be different each time the for loop is called. The 'disadvantage' is that the for loop is guaranteed to call the member function on *every* item of the collection.

The Chain of Responsibility pattern can be made to 'iterate' through the collection, but it is difficult to change the collection and have to update all the links between items. Also, since this is recursion, you could get a stack overflow!

However, the Chain of Responsibility really shines when it comes to terminating the loop: Any member can either decide to handle the call itself and return immediately, or just forward to the next item.

Answer (score 0):

Why to complicate the simple code by creating list and calling it "chain of responsibility"?

```
std::vector<Layer> layers(10);
for(Layer& hidden : layers)
{
  // prepare for activation aka do something
  hidden.activation();
}
```

What you do not like about this approach?

Comment: What is the difference here, w.r.t the original post? Can you not encapsulate `// prepare for activation ...` part inside `activation`?

Comment: well, depending on each level, you might need to do some specific processing before activation, if(layer(4)) then process this way for example

Comment: Exactly. We don't know how the `Layer`s are defined. Maybe they have `template<class Task> void settask(Task&& t);` member function. Then, each layer knows what to do, internally, inside their `activation` member function. In this question, I do not think this is clear. As others have posted, I do believe that the second version puts more constraint on the structure by exposing the layers to each other.

Comment: not sure, everything that can be modified with the second version can be done in this as well. furthermore, the question was about of disadvantages and chain. I am not an OOD guru, but this was not a Chain of Responsibility as well. And on disadvantages perspective, there are no disadvantages apart from more ugly and complicated code

Comment: Agreed in your last sentence. Thanks for the fruitful discussions.

Comment: Thank you all for you interesting remarks
@EduardRostomyan why it's not the Chain-of-responsibility pattern ? In my example, Layer is an abstract class. Else what's the name of this "pattern" ?

Comment: If you can tell me why it is, I will tell you why it is not. You dont understand the very definition of Chain pattern.

Answer (score 0):

The first example; each layer is completely independent of the next.  This means that they know nothing about other layers - they may or may not exist; and have only a need to focus on a single responsibility.

The second; the layers are now not only aware that there are other layers, but also are aware that it's a linked list.  What if a layer 2 and 3 are independent of each other but just depend on 1?  The ability to represent that is lost.  Ultimately, the item that controls the layers no longer has any ability to store them how it wants, leading to it being a poor design because it's working towards a god object.